# Opticon OPN-3002i no ttyUSB0

Tags: usb, serial-port

I have an Opticon OPN-3002i that I would like to have working on Linux, currently my computer runs Kali Linux. Unfortunately, the device doesn't show up as `ttyUSB0`, despite me setting it to USB-VCP mode. Here is the dmesg when I unplug and plug in the device.

```
[754566.684401] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 17
[754570.040249] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 18 using uhci_hcd
[754570.213170] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=065a, idProduct=a002
[754570.213185] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[754570.213196] usb 2-1: Product: USB Code Reader
[754570.213205] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Optoelectronics Co., Ltd.
[754608.100374] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 18
[754611.968205] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 19 using uhci_hcd
[754612.142243] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=065a, idProduct=a002
[754612.142260] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[754612.142271] usb 2-1: Product: USB Code Reader
[754612.142280] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Optoelectronics Co., Ltd.
[754853.620426] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 19
[754858.460183] usb 2-1: new full-speed USB device number 20 using uhci_hcd
[754858.634224] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=065a, idProduct=a002
[754858.634240] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[754858.634250] usb 2-1: Product: USB Code Reader
[754858.634259] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Optoelectronics Co., Ltd.
```

lsusb entry

```
Bus 002 Device 020: ID 065a:a002 Optoelectronics Co., Ltd 
Device Descriptor:
  bLength                18
  bDescriptorType         1
  bcdUSB               2.00
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceSubClass         0 
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x065a Optoelectronics Co., Ltd
  idProduct          0xa002 
  bcdDevice            1.00
  iManufacturer           1 Optoelectronics Co., Ltd.
  iProduct                2 USB Code Reader
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
    bDescriptorType         2
    wTotalLength           25
    bNumInterfaces          1
    bConfigurationValue     1
    iConfiguration          4 USB VCP Code Reader  
    bmAttributes         0x80
      (Bus Powered)
    MaxPower              500mA
    Interface Descriptor:
      bLength                 9
      bDescriptorType         4
      bInterfaceNumber        0
      bAlternateSetting       0
      bNumEndpoints           1
      bInterfaceClass       255 Vendor Specific Class
      bInterfaceSubClass      0 
      bInterfaceProtocol      0 
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            2
          Transfer Type            Bulk
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
        bInterval               5
Device Status:     0x0000
  (Bus Powered)
```

My research on it lead me to these two pages

- [Installing the Linux USB-VCP driver](http://wiki.opticon.com/index.php/Installing_the_Linux_USB-VCP_driver)
- [Opticon wiki Linux](https://wiki.opticonusa.com/techsupport/en/Linux)

The issue with the first link (Installing USB-VCP) is that my computer doesn't have a `/proc/bus/usb` folder, and I can't make one or mount it using `mount -t usbfs procbususb /proc/bus/usb`. From my understanding usbfs has been phased out. I really need this device in a ttyUSB mode so I can send commands via serial. The device itself is set to USB-VCP mode according to `lsusb`.

EDIT:

Ran the `usb-devices` program from terminal and got this for my device.

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#= 23 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=065a ProdID=a002 Rev=01.00
S:  Manufacturer=Optoelectronics Co., Ltd.
S:  Product=USB Code Reader
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to force the opticon device to use the opticon driver. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442833/forcing-driver-to-device-match#442867

It's as easy as echoing the vendor id and product id into the new_id file.

`echo 0x065a 0xa002 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/opticon/new_id`
Unplug and replug to ensure the driver works.